# How do i get the sqlite3 column

Tags: python-2.7, sqlite

My code:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect("keywords.db")

def search_location(name2):
    name3 = ' '.join(name2)
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute('SELECT location FROM INPUT WHERE id = ?', (name3,))
    for (location,) in c:
        print name3.capitalize(),':' '\n',location
        break
    else:
        pass  # not found
```

Sqlite table:

sqlite>

```
CREATE TABLE input(
   ID INT PRIMARY KEY     AUTOINCRREMENT, NOT NULL,
   NAME           TEXT    NOT NULL,
   AGE            INT     NOT NULL,
   ADDRESS        CHAR(50),
   SALARY         ....
);
```

I keep getting the error: No column LOCATION found. Items in name3 are to match the items in column NAME. If I change the code to read :

```
'SELECT NAME FROM INPUT WHERE id = ?', (name3,)
```

The error is the same. Please refer to the question I had asked earlier on [How to improve sqlite database request and speed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23439718/how-to-improve-sqlite-database-request-and-speed)

Comment: When you execute `SELECT Name ...`, you get the error `no column location found`? Really?

Comment: Umm ... it seems obvious as there is no Location column in your create statement.